# Looking for database schema for Intergy database

Tags: database-schema, progress-db

Can someone point me towards a source for schema definition for the Intergy database? It's a Medical Practice Management database by a company named Vitera (Intergy used to be owned by Sage). The database engine is Progress. Basically, what I'm looking for is the table names, the associated columns, and the Primary/Foreign Keys. I've gone to Vitera, and have been told that this info is proprietary. I've built a simple web app that peeks at the Progress catalog tables, and this has gotten me part of the way. But, it would be nice to get a little more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that weighed in here. I spoke to some folks at Progress, and the partner is well within their rights to withhold the schema from the database. I'm not sure why they would choose to attempt to protect it, though. The catalog views tell me a great deal. It just ended up costing one of their customers more than it should have to build the necessary database extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get to the catalog tables you've got what you need.  You probably just need a little understanding of the relationships between _file, _field and _index to complete the picture.

_file = table

_field = column

As Tim points out there are no explicit foreign keys and so forth.

Fields are related to tables by a common "recid".  I'm not a SQL guy and won't pretend to be one but the 4GL version of the query relating them is:

```
for each _file no-lock where _tbl-type = "t":

  display _file-name.

  for each _field no-lock where _field._file-recid = recid( _file ):

    display _field-name.

  end.

  for each _index no-lock where _index._file-recid = recid( _file ):

    display _index-name.

    for each _index-field no-lock where _index-field._index-recid = recid( _index ):

      find _field no-lock where recid( _field ) = _index-field._field-recid.
      display _field-name.

    end.

  end.

end.
```

It should be fairly obvious how to convert that to SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've seen your name on some other Progress posts, and I appreciate you taking the time to weigh in. As I mentioned above, I have been able to build some simple queries against the the Progress Catalog Views (SYSTABLES, SYSCOLUMNS, & SYSINDEXES). This has allowed me to a list of tables, and then via a hyperlink show the columns for a given table, plus any tables that have the selected table's primary key columns. This get's me part of the way, but I'm missing a couple of things, 1) Parent Tables back the other way, and 2) tables related by columns that don't match by name.

Comment: I am looking for specific help with the Intergy schema.

Comment: So you're looking more for documentation of the relationships and meaning of the tables & fields?  Sorry, I can't help with that.  I did once recover a broken Intergy db but have had no other contact with it.  As a company they are infamously controlling of all access and knowledge.  IMHO that's a very bad long-term strategy but they've not asked for my advice on the matter :(

Answer (score 0):

Progress uses a "Data Admin Tool" to manage the schema, and it'll dump a "df" file for you which'll have the db's schema structure.

It's not a SQL db though, so there's no "primary / foreign key" implemented in the db, so you'll have to infer any relationships between the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to find out where the Progress DB is running; I don't even know what kind of OS it's running on, Windows, Linux, etc.  Is this Data Admin Tool something that runs on the server the Progress itself is running on?

Comment: The tool can be run on the native server, or if the PC has client networking installed, it can be run remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the customer that you are supporting and see if they are paying for ODBC access as the schema is something they get with a paid subscription. If not then I am guessing they may be in violation of their contract with their vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did check with some folks at Progress, and their partner is really under no obligation to share their schema.